# How often do people use "would" when they are talking about past events?

Tags: past-tense, simple-past, would

I've recently learned from a grammar book that in English we can use "would" to describe repeated actions in the past. Actually, I try reading a lot books in English, listening to songs, aticles from magazines, watching movies and I haven't faced with that people use "would" for describing repeated actions in the past. So, my question, how often you use that ?
Or it's quite good to use the Past tense "I helped my parents in the store every school break" or "I would help my parents in the store every school break" ?

p.s. or in the example above it should be like "I used to help my parents in the store every school break" ?

Comment: It seems (from a rather untrustworthy Google Ngrams search) that this usage is [increasing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+child+I+would%2C+as+a+child+I+used&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20child%20I%20would%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20child%20I%20used%3B%2Cc0), at least in writing. Not at all what I would have guessed.

Comment: This is a better place to ask this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's quite commonly used when people tell stories about what they used to do.  For example, *When we were kids, we would play baseball every day after school.*

Comment: @MJF why ? What the difference ? But thanks anyway

Comment: Excuse me, in my example above all sentences are correct ?

Comment: About the correctness of your example sentences, you could say: _I used to help my parents in the store during every school break_. But besides that, your question needs a lot more editing. And about http://ell.stackexchange.com/ , people ask their more basic questions there. :)

Comment: The question is fine, the grammar is not perfect, but it's clear and comprehensible. Don't worry about it! :) John Lawler's edit was necessary for comprehension.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah. I guess I shouldn't be such a bother.

Comment: @MJF no, you're right that there are errors, but they're minor, and don't impede comprehension. Saying that, I'd correct the typo: aticles, it should be ARTICLES. As for not hearing speakers say "would", that's because it's often contracted, e.g. *Every Saturday, **we'd go** down to the river and fish*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both **used to** and **would** can be used to describe habitual actions in the past.  However, **would** is usually used only if when a specific time frame or scenario is given, whereas **used to** may "sound right" whether a time frame is given or not.

- When we were in high school, we **used to/would** have parties in people's houses because we were too young to meet in bars.
- I **used to** see him around the neighborhood.  (But not:  *I **would**  see him around the neighborhood.--no time frame) (Adding a scenario like the following would make **would** fine:)
- Whenever I walked my dog around the neighborhood, I **would/used to** see him.

Also, it seems to me that **would** emphasizes that the action stopped because the time frame ended (first example above), not because the person just started acting differently.

The framing of **would** is probably necessitated by its conditional meaning (e.g.: I **would** marry her in a second!)

Comment: Nice analysis of framing requirement. Btw, shouldn't that be _e.g._ in the last paragraph? And I don't get the conditional meaning of _would_ in _I would marry her ..._ . That's just future in the past, I think.

Comment: @MJF--It is the conditional use of would, implying "I would marry her if she would only agree."

Comment: I can't thank both of you enough :) 
Excuse me, do the following sentences sound weird or wrong ?

1) "I would see him around the neighborhood **every day**."
2) "I would see him around the neighborhood **for 5 years**."
3) "I **quite often** would see him around the neighborhood **when he arrived to ring in Christmas with his parents**."

Comment: 1) OK if there's a time frame (not necessarily in the same sentence).  2) Use simple past (I saw him).  3) Good, but more commonly, "I would quite often see him..."

Answer (score 2):

I think "would" in that context means "used to"

Comment: How often do you use "would" instead "used to" in life ? What the word/sentense between those people usually use ? Both ?